# Will I have any collisions coming from the @ControllerAdvice if I use it to populate a @ModelAttribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

This is the main controller for the web entrypoint

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/webapp")
public class WebAppController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/home/{authKey}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
String index(@ModelAttribute MyMeta myMeta, Model model){

    System.out.println("Token: "+myMeta.getAccessToken());

    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/config/{authKey}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
String config(@ModelAttribute MyMeta myMeta, Model model){

    return "configure";
}
}
```

Now if you look at the interceptor you can see how I am creating the @ModelAttribute, and see the implementation

```
@Component
@ControllerAdvice
public class SessionInterceptor implements AsyncHandlerInterceptor {

MyMeta myMeta;

...

@ModelAttribute
public MyMeta getTest() {
    return this.myMeta;
}

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object o) throws Exception {

...

// parse the key from the request

... 

MetaMagicKey metaMagicKey = metaMagicKeyRepo.findKeyByMagicKey(key);

// do work here query my DB and build stuff

...

// assign the queried data built into object
this.myMeta = metaMagicKey.getId().getMyMeta();

return true;
}
```

My question is, I do not know the true inter-workings of Springboot so I am worried if too many people execute this I might have some object swapping, or some kind of collision? There really isn't a clean way to do this and all of the research I've done is torn between using HttpServletRequest#setAttribute() and using @ModelAttribute, I like the route I chose above as it's VERY easy to implement in my methods.

```
Springboot 1.4.2 - Java 8
```

### EDIT:

---

What I ended up trying is this, based on several pages I've read.

I created a new component:

```
@Component
@RequestScope
public class HWRequest implements Serializable {

private MyMeta myMeta;

public MyMeta getMyMeta() {
    return myMeta;
}

public void setMyMeta(MyMeta myMeta) {
    this.myMeta = myMeta;
}

}
```

And then My Config class

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

UserSessionInterceptor userSessionInterceptor;

@Autowired
public AppConfig(UserSessionInterceptor userSessionInterceptor) {
    this.userSessionInterceptor = userSessionInterceptor;
}

@Bean
@RequestScope
public HWRequest hwRequest() {
    return new HWRequest();
}

@Bean
public UserSessionInterceptor createUserSessionInterceptor() {
    return userSessionInterceptor;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
registry.addInterceptor(createUserSessionInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/user/**");
}
}
```

And here is the interceptor I modified

```
@Component
@ControllerAdvice
public class SessionInterceptor implements AsyncHandlerInterceptor {

@Resource
HWRequest hwRequest;

...

@ModelAttribute
public HWRequest getTest() {
    return this.hwRequest;
}

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object o) throws Exception {

...

// parse the key from the request

... 

MetaMagicKey metaMagicKey = metaMagicKeyRepo.findKeyByMagicKey(key);

// do work here query my DB and build stuff

...

// assign the queried data built into object
this.hwRequest.setMyMeta(metaMagicKey.getId().getMyMeta());

return true;
}
```

And of course the modified controller to fit my needs

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class WebAppUserController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/home/{authKey}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
String index(@ModelAttribute HWRequest request, Model model){

    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/config/{authKey}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
String config(@ModelAttribute HWRequest request, Model model){

    return "configure";
}

}
```

Based on all of the documentation I've read this should work, but maybe I am missing something as the interceptor is STILL a singleton. Maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myMeta` variable represents state in singleton bean. Of course it is not thread-safe and various users will get collisions. Do not ever store any of your application state in singleton beans.

If you want to store some state per request, use Spring's request scope. That means [creating separate bean just for storing state annotated with `@RequestScope` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/annotation/RequestScope.html)

**Reaction on EDIT:**

This bean registration can be deleted as it is already registered into Spring IoC container with `@Component` annotation:

```
@Bean
@RequestScope
public HWRequest hwRequest() {
    return new HWRequest();
}
```

Another piece that is not needed in your AppConfig is autowiring `UserSessionInterceptor` bean and registering it as bean again. Delete that. As that bean is being autowired it obviously already is in IoC container, so no need to register it again.

Another confusing piece is workd `session` in naming. As you are dealing with `@RequestScope` instead of `@SessionScope` I would advise to change naming of your class to `request` (e.g. `RequestInterceptor`). Session vs Request are very different beasts.

Otherwise it looks like it can work and should be thread safe.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I've added an edit and the solution I came up with based on things that I read in the documents and several examples I found. Does this sound viable to you?

Thank you again

Comment: Also sorry about the accidental downvote, it will not let me change it for some reason.

Comment: NP, It should allow you to revisit your down-vote after I edited my answer.